# R DT: select specific columns in an interactive htmlwidget DT datatable

Tags: r, dt

I have a dataset that let's say has two columns. One column is for score and the other is for the actual value. I would like to colour the actual value column based on the score column, then remove the score column. I already did this but I can not remove the score column using `DT::datatable` options. Remember, by datatable I mean `DT::datatable()` the interactive interface html widget table.

```
## Sample df  ##

df = data.frame(
    actual = sample(1:10),
    score = runif(10)
)

----------

## Coloring breaks ##

brks <- quantile(df, probs = seq(.05, .95, .05), na.rm = TRUE)
clrs <- round(seq(255, 40, length.out = length(brks) + 1), 0) %>%
  {paste0("rgb(255,", ., ",", ., ")")}

----------

## Generating DT ##

datatable(df) %>% formatStyle(
  'actual', 'score',
  backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks, clrs))
```

More information here about styling:

[DT Styling](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html)

**Not applicable workaround**

You can select columns first prior generating a datatable. i.e `df %>% select(actual) %>% datatable(.)` but that does not work in my case because I have to do the styling first, then select from that html widget.

**Expected workaround**

I'd like an option to specify which columns to select using `DT::datatable()` (the value column **only** here in this case), multiple columns in my real case.

So the question is how to select a value column using the below syntax?

```
datatable(df)
```

There is an options called `selected` but it says it works for shiny.
I have read about [options](https://datatables.net/reference/option/select.items) and there is a `select.item` that might work, but I might be missing the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to hide/make-visible the columns. To hide them:

This is done by option `columnDefs` that takes boolean for visibility and the target columns. You can supply multiple one using vector a `c()`

```
datatable(df, 
          options = list(columnDefs = 
                           list(
                                  list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(2))
                               )
                         )) %>% 
  formatStyle(
  'actual', 'score',
  backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks, clrs))
```